# redireccionar url después de respuesta ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

He visto que para redireccionar tras ejecutar una función en javascript existen dos maneras. En mi caso, que quiero ir al index, sería:

```
window.location.href="../index.php";
window.location.replace("../index.php");
```

Mi problema es el siguiente. Cuando envío los datos de un formulario al controlador a través del post, hago saltar un alert y luego  redirecciono. Todo lo hace bien, sin embargo, el redireccionamiento es inmediato y apenas se aprecia el alert... Incluso poniendo un botón de confirmación,en el alert, se lo salta...

```
function insertarEmpleadoBD(datos){
//Llamada a AJAX

    //Crear el objeto
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //Abrir la conexión
    xhr.open('POST', '../controller/empleadoControlador.php', true);
    //Pasar los datos
    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        if(this.status === 200)
        {
         Swal.fire({
         position: 'center',
         type: 'success',
         title: 'El empleado ha sido dado de alta',
         showConfirmButton: false,
         timer: 1500
         })
        }
        window.location.replace("../index.php");
    }
    //Enviar los datos
    xhr.send(datos)
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de que ejecute el redireccionamiento un par de segundos más tarde?

Comment: podrías colocar un `setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("../index.php"); }, 3000);` para redireccionar a los 3 segundos... porque imagina que no tienes ningún botón de llamada a la acción, deberías entonces realizarlo con un temporizador

Comment: SI!!! Funciona perfecto!!! Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para retrasar el redireccionamiento puedes usar *setTimeOut* en  tu caso

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace("../index.php");},2000);
```

Tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
function insertarEmpleadoBD(datos){
//Llamada a AJAX

    //Crear el objeto
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //Abrir la conexión
    xhr.open('POST', '../controller/empleadoControlador.php', true);
    //Pasar los datos
    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        if(this.status === 200)
        {
         Swal.fire({
         position: 'center',
         type: 'success',
         title: 'El empleado ha sido dado de alta',
         showConfirmButton: false,
         timer: 1500
         })
        }
        setTimeout(
          function(){window.location.replace("../index.php");}
          ,2000);
    }
    //Enviar los datos
    xhr.send(datos)
}
```